# Soap client insert call in PHP

Tags: php, web-services, soap, soap-client, dto

Hope someone can help me with a SOAP client call from PHP

I need to call a SOAP service and send a DTO object which the service can insert

### The SOAP documentation are like the following

```
public virtual resultValidation validateInvoice(
    Invoice invoice
)

invoice: 
    Type: invoiceWebService.DTO.invoice
```

---

I need to pass the following "variables" in the invoice object

```
"productNameInvoice" (VALUE: "Produkt 1")
"amount" (VALUE: 500)
"type" (VALUE: 1)
```

I have tried to do the following code (which I use for get calls), but it dosent work.
I guess it is because I sent "the variables" as an array instead of and DTO object (invoiceWebService.DTO.invoice) - but can figure out what to change

Get this error: Uncaught SoapFault exception -  Non-static method requires a target

### This is the code I have tried

```
$client = new soapClient(...) // As I use to when getting from service (is working)

$params = array(
  "productNameInvoice"=>"Product 1",
  "amount"=>500,
  "type"=>1
);

$response = $client->__soapCall("validateInvoice", array($params))
```

---

Hope someone can help me :)

In advance - thank you
Kim

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
$client = new soapClient(...) 
$validateInvoice = new stdClass();
$validateInvoice->productNameInvoice = "Product 1";
$validateInvoice->amount = 500;
$validateInvoice->type = 1;
$response = $client->validateInvoice($validateInvoice);
```

Comment: Hi - thanks for the answer. I have now tried that, but get this error: Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [s:Client] Non-static method requires a target

Do you know why that happen?

Comment: Any suggestions? @miknik

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution by using miknik's answer

```
$client = new soapClient(...) 
$validateInvoice = new stdClass();
$validateInvoice->productNameInvoice = "Product 1";
$validateInvoice->amount = 500;
$validateInvoice->type = 1;

$params = array(
    "invoice" => $validateInvoice
);

$response = $client->__soapCall("validateInvoice", array($params));
```